# Problema ao publicar um site iis 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Preciso publicar um site que está em asp.net mvc e quando publico e altero os arquivos na pasta existente no iis 6, as alterações que eu fiz no projeto não aparecem quando abro o site pelo iis. Tenho uma pasta dentro da Models que tem uma role e nos arquivos da pasta quando publico, essa role não aparece. Será isso o problema ou publica o projeto todo ?

Comment: você reiniciou o IIS após fazer as alterções?

Comment: Sim, reiniciei @HiagoSouza

Comment: Depois que vc altera, fecha e abre novamente o arquivo. Suas alterações ainda estão lá?

Comment: Que tipo de alteração? é nos seus arquivos ou nas configurações do IIS?

Comment: No projeto que está em asp.net mvc. Fiz uma alteração numa página cshtml e preciso subir essa alteração para o iis, mas essas alterações não estão aparecendo lá. Já publiquei um monte de vezes e nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando um procedimento fora do padrão para publicar. Por isso não há garantias de que o site esteja atualizado.

Utilize o comando <kbd>Publish</kbd> para publicar seu projeto para o diretório do IIS.

Comment: eu dei um publish do visual studio tals, fiz o procedimento certo e nada ..

Comment: Agora o problema é o seguinte, a aplicação abre mas quando clico em entrar após colocar o login e a senha, a página abre em branco.

Comment: O que aparece no *Event Viewer* do Windows?

Comment: Como testa isso ?